# How to set exist value as selected in dropdown list without hardcoding items in dropdownlist using asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have form in asp.net mvc that retrieves records from database.this form have dropdowns. in Edit action of controller it is must to have selected the already inserted items. suppose if i am taking the User information for edit, then its City,State and country must be selected as they inserted before.Can any one tell me how to set values from database as selected in drop down list when page loads???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a user model with State as property you need to do the following for your view

```
 <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, (SelectList)ViewBag.StateDDL)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
 </div>
```

here is the code for the controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{   
    UserModel myuser = new UserModel();

    Get the user data from database here
    myuser.State = "AZ";


    List<SelectListItem> mystate= new List<SelectListItem>();
    SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
    item.Text = " - SELECT - ";
    item.Value = "";
    mystate.Add(item);

    item = new SelectListItem();
    item.Text = "CA";
    item.Value = "CA";
    mystate.Add(item);

    item = new SelectListItem();
    item.Text = "AZ";
    item.Value = "Az";
    mystate.Add(item);

    ViewBag.StateDDL = new SelectList(mystate.AsEnumerable(), "Value", "Text", myuser .State);
    return View(myuser);
}
```

Comment: When i use above code,i have an error "The name ViewBag does not exist in the current context".Can u help to fix that error??

Comment: which version of mvc do you use?  my code was with mvc3.  If you are on mvc2 I think its called ViewData

Comment: Thanx.Its working. Is it possible to dynamic fill dropdown list from database and select one item as selected in above code?

Comment: yeah, just pull the data from the database and loop through it and add the item mystate on each iteration.